# Use Jackson to write yaml?

Tags: java, json, jackson, yaml

I'm using Jackson to read and modify yaml files. Works great. I can't find the magic incantations needed to write the yaml, though.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode)mapper.readTree(yamlFileIn);
// modify root here
mapper.writeValue(yamlFileOut, root); // writes json, not yaml. not sure why.
```

I'm sure it's some combination of writers, JsonGenerators, and something else. Anyone got sample code?

Comment: The code as indicated should work -- maybe there is a bug. Make sure to use a recent version (2.4.4). It is possible that `YAMLFactory` might be missing some override, leading to accidental use of JSON generator.

Comment: FWIW, issue 12 (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml/issues/12) that was fixed in 2.1.3 could have problem described.

Answer (score 8):

For v2.8.3 the following should work:

```
YAMLFactory yf = new YAMLFactory();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(yf);
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(yamlFileIn);
// modify root here     
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yamlFileOut);
SequenceWriter sw = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValues(fos);
sw.write(root);
```

Comment: Yep, this works for recent versions of Jackson.  The other does not.  It is superior, because you can reuse the already configured mapper/yamlfactory if you are also reading files.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
YAMLFactory yf = new YAMLFactory();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(yf);
ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(yamlFileIn);
// modify root here     
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(yamlFileOut);
yf.createGenerator(fos).writeObject(root); // works. yay.
```

Comment: Note that with v2.8.3 this answer might produce the exception `No ObjectCodec defined for the generator`. Using the mapper to write the value seems to be the preferred solution.

Comment: @dave-jarvis is correct about v2.8.3. This will produce the 'No ObjectCodec defined for the generator ..' exception.

Comment: @DaveJarvis gilbertpilz's answer above has the fix for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39732593/467240