# Removing braces and brackets from Java Jackson's JSON output?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to create a JSON document by using Jackson. The hierarchy goes as follows:

Event:

```
class Event {
  private String name = "";
  private Set<Integer> admin = new HashSet<>();
  private List<House> houseList = new ArrayList<>();

  }
```

House:

```
class House {
  private List<OG> OGList = new ArrayList<>();
  private int score = 0;
  private String name = "";
}
```

Group:

```
class OG {
  private int score = 0;
  private int id = 0;

}
```

Every event might comprises of a set number of houses, which in turn comprises of a set number of groups. Each house and group has a score modifier as well.

Currently, this is how I print the JSON document using the pretty print method:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File f = new File("./db/" + dir);

    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
      return "This event name is taken. Please try again.";
    }
    try {
      mapper.writeValue(f, event);

      // Convert object to JSON string and pretty print
      String jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(event);
      System.out.println(jsonInString);
  }
}
```

The resulting output is pretty ugly:

```
{
  "name" : "test",
  "admin" : [ 423766405 ],
  "houseList" : [ {
    "score" : 0,
    "name" : "first",
    "oglist" : [ {
      "score" : 0,
      "id" : 0
    }, {
      "score" : 0,
      "id" : 1
    }, {
      "score" : 0,
      "id" : 2
    } ]
  ..
}
```

Is there a better way to format the output, for example:

```
name: 
  test
admin:
  a
  b
  c
  houses:
    name:
      first
      group:
        1
        ..
```

Comment: It's outputting the object as JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) and the 'ugly' format is just in fact what JSON is: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html  You may be better inclined to use something that outputs YAML

Comment: You can have Jackson write YAML as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46445834/14955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like you want to output [YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), not [JSON](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46447267/101095) shows how simple it is to write YAML output to a file using Jackson.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39732593/101095) shows how to read a YAML file, modify it's contents, and save it back out again.

Comment: If i save the file as YAML format, would I be able to get an object back if needed? Or should the file be saved as a JSON document, but printed as YAML output. so that I can convert it back to a Java Object?

Comment: Hah, the original post I wrote showed how to do exactly that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734153/use-jackson-to-write-yaml/39732593#39732593  This shows how a person can use Jackson to read and modify YAML files